# Creating dictionary from a file? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to store the contents of a file into a dictionary, and I thought I was doing it right, but It doesn't print out all of the contents, just the first line. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me?

The file I am using (mood.txt):

```
happy, Jennifer Clause
sad, Jonathan Bower
mad, Penny
excited, Logan 
awkward, Mason Tyme
```

my code:

```
def bringFile():

    moodFile = open("mood.txt")
    moodread = moodFile.readlines()
    moodFile.close()
    return moodread


def makemyDict(theFile):
    for i in theFile:
        (mood, name) = lines.split(",")

        moodDict = {mood : name}

        #print the dictionary   

        for m in moodDict:
            return(m, name)


def main():

    moodFile = bringFile()

    mDict = makemyDict(moodFile)

    print(mDict)
```

I am trying to check if the dictionary is actually working, which is why I am printing it out for now. Every time I try to print it outputs:

```
('happy', ' Jennifer Clause\n')
```

I am trying to have all the elements separated by mood/name inside so I can use them later, But it only seems to be printing out one pair. I feel like all my steps were right so I have no idea what I should do!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what the `return` statement does?

Comment: It looks like you're unclear on assignment vs. mutation, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bringFile():
    moodFile = open("mood.txt",'r')
    moodread = moodFile.readlines()
    moodFile.close()
    return moodread

def makemyDict(theFile):
    moodDict = {}
    for lines in theFile:
        mood, name = lines.split(",")

        moodDict[mood] = name

    return (moodDict)
        #print the dictionary

        # for m in moodDict:
        #     return(m, name)
        # print(lines)

def main():

    moodFile = bringFile()
    Dict = makemyDict(moodFile)
    print(Dict)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the entire dictionary for every loop,
use `moodDict[mood] = name` to set just a single key value pair.

You are also returning inside the loop which will completely short-circuit the function. you should either move the `for m in moodDict` loop outside of the outer loop and use `print` instead of `return`, or just use a `return moodDict` at the end of the function instead and print them out outside the function.

Another note, you may want to call `mood.strip()` and `name.strip()` to remove whitespace from each as well.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it!! I think I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside the for loop, so basically it just enter the for loop once and return. Also, you are creating new dictionary that ovewrite moodDict at every iteration.

```
def makemyDict(theFile):
    moodDict = {} # create the dictionary
    for i in theFile:
        (mood, name) = lines.split(",")
        moodDict['mood'] = name.strip() # strip off leading and trailing space
    return moodDict
```

By the way, whole code can be simplify as below

```
def makemyDict(theFile):
    moodDict = {} # create the dictionary
    with open(theFile) as f:
        for line in f:
            (mood, name) = lines.split(",")
            moodDict['mood'] = name.strip() # strip off leading and trailing space
    return moodDict

d = makemyDict('mood.txt')
print(d)
```

Comment: best thanks is to upvote and/or accept the answer that you found most useful :) it help others as well when they face similar issue

Answer (score 0):

```
def line_gen(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        _ = (i.replace('\n', '').split(', ') for i in f)
        yield from _

m_dict = dict([*line_gen('mode.txt')])
print(m_dict)
```

out:

```
{'awkward': 'Mason Tyme', 'excited': 'Logan', 'sad': 'Jonathan Bower', 'mad': 'Penny', 'happy': 'Jennifer Clause'}
```